# Timestampable for the first time a field was set

Tags: symfony

I have a `state` (state machine value) property on an entity and am setting datetime fields based on when the entity transitions to a given state.

Task states: (simplified)

- new
- in_progress
- complete

A task can transition back into `in_progress` after it is set to `complete`, but I want to use timestampable to set a `$dateStarted` property only on first time it transitions to `in_progress`.

This code will always set `$dateStarted` to the last time `$state` transitions to `in_progress`.

Is there a way to configure it so `$dateStarted` is only set the first time the task transitions to `in_progress`?

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field="state", value="in_progress")
 */
private $dateStarted;
```

Comment: `Timestampable` is not able to use expressions or callbacks, use a [`preUpdate` lifecycle callback](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) instead. Then you can add a conditional event to update the field as desired. `if ($this->state === 'in_progress' && null === $this->dateStarted) { $this->dateStarted = new \DateTime(); }`

Comment: @fyrye Ocramius from the Doctrine team gave advices to avoid lifecycle callbacks (https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/58 https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/59)

Comment: @Franckgamess Timestampable IS a lifecycle call back, it uses onFlush.. However I agree, it makes code less manageable, adds unnecessary overhead and the same can be accomplished in the `setState` method.

Answer (score 2):

Like Fyrye says you can use a lifecycle callback with a function to set your date just once. I use it like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setTheStartDate()
{
    if ($this->getState() === 'in_progress' && $this->getDateStarted === null) {
        $this->setDateStarted(new \DateTime('now'));
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you have the following annotation on your class to enable the lifecycle callbacks:

```
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```

Comment: You should rely on strict comparison operators `=== null` or `!== null` to avoid loose comparison potential pitfalls. Such as [`0 == null`, `'' == null`, `false == null`, `array() == null` https://3v4l.org/p5FYo](https://3v4l.org/p5FYo)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, `Timestampable` is not able to use expressions or a callback method to evaluate the changed value. While you can use a lifecycle callback to accomplish your desired result. Lifecycle callbacks do add an extra layer of overhead and complexity to your entity, that is difficult to track down issues that arise from them and expanding your code in the future more tedious. 
One example when using Timestampable or Lifecycle callbacks; the `dateStarted` will not be set until **AFTER** you have flushed your changes to the database. This causes referencing the `dateStarted` value in other business logic impossible until you have sent them to the database.

Therefor it is recommended instead to place your business logic in the `setState` method. Doing so will enforce the desired `dateStarted` assignment rules. This also allows you to use additional business logic, like ensuring that the state does not jump from `new` to `complete`, without first being set to `in_progress`, etc.

Example: https://3v4l.org/s9PJu

```
class MyEntity
{

    const STATE_NEW = 'new';
    const STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress';
    const STATE_COMPLETE = 'complete';
    const CONFIG_STATES = array(
        self::STATE_NEW,
        self::STATE_IN_PROGRESS,
        self::STATE_COMPLETE
    );

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateStarted;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $state = self::STATE_NEW;

    /**
     * @var string|null $state
     */
    public function setState($state = null)
    {
        $this->validateState($state);
        $this->updateStateDate($state);
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function getDateStarted()
    {
        return $this->dateStarted;
    }

    /**
     * used to update the started date when the state changes to in_progress
     * @var string $state
     */
    protected function updateStateDate($state) 
    {
        if ($this->state !== $state && $state === self::STATE_IN_PROGRESS && $this->dateStarted === null) {
            $this->dateStarted = new \DateTime();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function validateState($state)
    {
       if (!in_array($state, self::CONFIG_STATES, true)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Unknown state "%s". Expected one of: "%s"', 
                    $state, 
                    implode('", "', self::CONFIG_STATES)
                )
            );
        }
        if ($this->state === self::STATE_NEW && $state !== self::STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Invalid state "%s" specified, Expected: %s', 
                    $state, 
                    self::STATE_IN_PROGRESS
                )
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//default state = "new", dateStarted = null
$entity = new \MyEntity;

//state = "in_progress",  dateStarted = \DateTime('now')
$entity->setState(MyEntity::STATE_IN_PROGRESS); 
//NOTE - $entity->getDateStarted()  will return a value now without first using $em->flush();

//only changes state to "complete", leaves the previously assigned date
$entity->setState(MyEntity::STATE_COMPLETE);

//only changes state to "in_progress", leaves the previously assigned date
$entity->setState(MyEntity::STATE_IN_PROGRESS);
```

---

I also suggest, if not done so already, converting your `state` field from a string to an associated entity. You can then remove the `STATE` constants and check within `validateState`, since the foreign key constraint will enforce a valid state assignment.

---

As a final note, since you are using the Symfony framework, you can alternatively utilize [Form validation constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) and move your business logic into those constraints/callbacks, which will be validated when the forms are submitted and alter your entity and display friendly messages accordingly.